# VSCode doesn't detect my custom colorscheme extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I generated a fresh colorscheme extension with yo, copied the resulting folder to ~/.vscode-oss/extensions/, restart VSCode and search the colorscheme, but it doesn't seem to detect the extension! Note that I can debug the extension and it works well. What am I doing wrong?

This is the contents of the folder:

```bash
$ pwd
/home/username/.vscode-oss/extensions/kalm
$ tree -a
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── .git
│   ├── ...
│   ...
├── .gitattributes
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── themes
│   └── Kalm-color-theme.json
├── vsc-extension-quickstart.md
├── .vscode
│   └── launch.json
└── .vscodeignore

13 directories, 27 files
```

BTW, I found this on the extensions folder:

```bash
$ pwd
/home/username/.vscode-oss/extensions
$ cat .obsolete
{"undefined_publisher.kalm-0.0.1":true}
$ # Does the extension have something to do with this?
```

Comment: why put `.git` folder in there, what is the content of `package.json`, does debugging the theme work

Comment: what is the purpose of `vsc-extension-quickstart.md` , `.vscode` folder, `.vscodeignore`, `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes`

Comment: one of the log panels shows the activation of all the extensions

Comment: You should package the extension (using `vsce package`) and install it using the `Install .vsix` file instead of manually copying the files to the extension folder. Also, debugging the extension prior to install would help you to detect issues. Once you used `yo code` to create a new extension, the debugging is easy to use (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension#debugging-the-extension)

Comment: What happens if you rename the extension directory to `kalm-0.0.1-universal`? It seems to me that the extension loading logic in VSCodium changed recently to require version and platform in the name. By the way, you can test whether it detects your extension with the command `codium --list-extensions`.